# Does default destructor free the memory pointed by the member pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

When I delete a node in a linked list, do I need to set the `next` to NULL?

The ListNode is defined as this

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode* next;
    ListNode(int x): val(x) {}
}
```

Now I wanna delete the node after `m`

```
ListNode *tmp = m->next;
m->next = m->next->next;
delete tmp;
```

If `tmp->next` would be deleted in the destructor, the linked list should be in trouble. However, if `tmp->next` is not deleted, there could be another case that causes memory leak:

```
ListNode *tmp = new ListNode(0);
tmp->next = new ListNode(1);
delete tmp;
```

If `tmp->next` is not deleted, there's no way to find this piece of memory again.

So it's a dilemma here, what does the default destructor actually do?

Comment: It will not call delete on member pointer

Comment: How can default destructor possibly know whether to free that memory or not? There's no guarantee that that memory was even dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default destructor destroys all member variables (that have destructors) and does nothing else.

None of `ListNode`'s member variables have destructors, so the default destructor for `ListNode` does nothing.

Note that while `next` is a member variable, the thing `next` points to isn't.

Comment: So does it mean I should either delete `tmp->next` or give it another pointer before I delete `tmp`?

Comment: @KingstonChan You already have the information you need to answer that question. Do you think it does?

Comment: Thanks! you're very helpful!

Comment: @KingstonChan Do you think it does?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: @KingstonChan Why?

Comment: Because if I don't do so, I'll lose the piece of memory pointed by `tmp->next` forever, and not able to access / deallocate it.

Comment: @KingstonChan In the first case (remember the question contains two different code snippets), `m->next` still points to the same piece of memory as `tmp->next`. So if you delete the piece of memory, `m->next` is now pointing to unallocated memory - is that what you want? In the second case, yes, if you don't delete `tmp->next` now then you won't be able to delete it later, so you'll leak memory.

Comment: Thanks for elaboration! This confirms by guess.

Answer (score 0):

> So it's a dilemma here, what does the default destructor actually do?

The default destructor destroys the member variables. If the member variables have user defined destructors, they are called. If they are fundamental types, nothing happens.

There is more to it than what I described above. It will be worth your while to read up the section on destructors in the standard. In C++11, that section is 12.4. You can also find more information at [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor).